# Batch script escape space not working

Tags: batch-file, escaping, space

When I try to run the command

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\TorAES\certmgr.exe" -del -c -n "Certificatename" -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
```

in a Windows cmd.exe I get the errormessage (translated by me):
The command "C:\Program" is misspelled or does not exist.

even other combinations with " does not work:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C 'C:\Program Files (x86)\TorAES\certmgr.exe' -del -c -n 'Certificatename' -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "'C:\Program Files (x86)\TorAES\certmgr.exe' -del -c -n 'Certificatename' -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher"
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C \"C:\Program Files (x86)\TorAES\certmgr.exe\" -del -c -n \"Certificatename\" -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher
```

Unfortunately if I just run

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\TorAES\certmgr.exe"
```

certmgr.exe starts but (obvious) my arguments are missing and i really need them to automatic remove my certificate when uninstalling my program.

I am absolutly unfamiliar with batchscripting.
Is someone able to find my mistake?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `cmd /?`:

> If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is used to process quote (") characters:
>
> 1. If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters on the command line are preserved:
>
>    - no /S switch
>    - exactly two quote characters
>    - no special characters between the two quote characters,
>         where special is one of: &<>()@^|
>    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
>         two quote characters
>    - the string between the two quote characters is the name
>         of an executable file.
> 2. Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
>       a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
>       remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
>       any text after the last quote character.

So you can add an outer set of quotes:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C ""C:\Program Files (x86)\TorAES\certmgr.exe" -del -c -n "Certificatename" -s -r localMachine trustedpublisher"
```

Comment: Thank you! I just did not thought the command itself could be wrong. Your second solution works for me :D

Comment: You're welcome. My first solution was wrong - removed!